# Combo box updating on another form

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I'm looking for some advice to help with an access database form with combo boxes. Using Access 2010.
It is controlling our PDA assets I have one form - PDA details with tab control.

Along the tabs I have PDA Details and Contact Details.

PDA details gets it's information from a query - PDA Details (Q) 
and contact details gets its information from - Contacts (Q)

Both queries have a relationship to the contact name column.

Is there a way to when a PDA contact is selected - display the contact information for them on the contact details tab? like an update or code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the link child and master field of the subform controls.

The link master field should be set to the name of the listbox control or comboxbox control with the bound column set to the column that contains the relevant ID and the link child fields should be set to the contact ID.